# Best way to convert dictionary information into formatted strings (C#)

Tags: c#, user-interface, dictionary, formatting, categorization

I have a dictionary of words and the number of times they appear(String,int).

I need to then take this information and display it to a GUI after catorgorizing the words alphabetically or by frequency.The categorizes will be displayed and start with

"Words Starting with the letter _"

or wtih

"Words that occur _ times"

and then display the correct information. However the words display must also be formatted into a varying number of columns (1-6) that the user can change.

Mainly I am looking for any suggestions on how to categorize the information and the formatting.

*Also, I must use a dictionary that is sorted by linq which I already have

Comment: If you are looking to hire someone to do your work, there is a job posting section here.

Comment: I'm not though I just need a large help in direction, and maybe a example or two

Comment: As a whole nothing yet right now I am still attempting to categorize the words using linq and once i have done that i will try the formatting

Comment: At least show us the dictionary you already have. `However the words display must also be formatted into a varying number of columns (1-6) that the user can change.` what does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're calling categorization is referred to as "grouping" in LINQ. Check out the [Grouping samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea).